# Unable to resolve C2084 error: 'Function already has a body' - C++

Tags: c++

I am a beginner trying to practice the concept of Inheritance and tried building a piece of code but I seem to get this error. Maybe adding the virtual function is messing up my code?  Here are my header and source files below:

1. Employee.h

   ```
    #pragma once
    #include<string>

    class Employee {

    public:
    std::string name{};
    int salary{};

    Employee(std::string name, int salary);

    virtual void displayDetails() {}

    };
   ```
2. Manager.h:

   ```
    #pragma once

    #include<string>
    #include "Employee.h"

    class Manager : public Employee {

    private:
    std::string department{};

    public:
    Manager(std::string name, int salary, std::string department);
    void displayDetails() override {}

    };
   ```
3. Employee.cpp

   ```
   #include<iostream>
   #include "Employee.h"
   #include<string>

   Employee::Employee(std::string name, int salary) : name(name), salary(salary) {}

   void Employee::displayDetails() {
        std::cout << "Name: " << name << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Salary: " << salary << std::endl;
    }
   ```
4. Manager.cpp:

   ```
   #include<iostream>
   #include<string>
   #include "Manager.h"


   Manager::Manager(std::string name, int salary, std::string department) : 
   Employee(name, salary), department(department) {};
   void Manager::displayDetails(){
        std::cout << "Name: " << name << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Salary: " << salary << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Department: " << department << std::endl;
    }
   ```
5. Main.cpp:

   ```
   #include "Employee.h"
   #include "Manager.h"
   #include<string>


   int main()
   {
    Employee e1("Robert", 5000);
    Employee e2("Sam", 8000);

    e1.displayDetails();
    e2.displayDetails();

    Manager m("Ben", 15000, "Marketing");
    m.displayDetails();


    return 0;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line in `Employee.h`:
 `virtual void displayDetails() {}`

*Implements* `displayDetails`. The "body" of a function is what's in the brackets that follows its signature.

Therefore, when you attempt to "define" it in the `.cpp`, the compiler thinks you're trying to redefine the body because you already gave one in the header.

The correct syntax for what you're trying to do is

```cpp
 virtual void displayDetails();
//                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Which is a function *declaration* (no body, i.e. no *definition*).

And of course, the answer is the same for `Manager.h`/`Manager.cpp`.

Answer (score 2):

With

```
virtual void displayDetails() {}
```

you already have *defined* (implemented) the function.

Then you define (implement) it *again*, which isn't possible.

You should only *declare* the function in the class:

```
virtual void displayDetails();
```